# Outputs how many times you input

Tags: arrays, for-loop

My goal is to output the amount of how many times I filled up. Ex: I filled up 3 students, the program should output the 3 students too. I only need a simple for loop and array. Hope someone could help me. I've been struggling analyzing where to put the forloop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    NSO a = new NSO (); 
    int[]loop=new int[2];
    String[]ask={"Sure","Not for now"};


    a.setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: "));
    a.setGender(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter gender: "));
    a.setAddress(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address: "));
    a.setCourse(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter course: "));
    a.setAge(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter age: ")));
    a.setBday(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter birth date: ")));         

    int tanong=0;

    while(tanong==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

        tanong = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Do you want to input
                         another student?",null,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,ask,ask[0]);

    while(tanong==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

        a.setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: "));
        a.setGender(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter gender: "));
        a.setAddress(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address: "));
        a.setCourse(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter course: "));
        a.setAge(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter age: ")));
        a.setBday(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter birth date: ")));break;

        }

    }
    while(tanong==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\nName: " + a.getName()
                                    +"\nGender: " + a.getGender()
                                    +"\nAddress: " + a.getAddress()     
                                    +"\nCourse: " + a.getCourse()
                                    +"\nAge: " + a.getAge()
                                    +"\nBirth Date: " + a.getBday());break;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an example on how you could do it.

```
final int maxsize = 3;

NSO a[] = new NS0[maxsize];

// a for loop for the input
for (int i = 0; i < maxsize; i++) {
    a[i].setNames(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: "));
    a[i].setGender....
    etc.
}

// a for loop for the output
for (int j = 0; j < maxsize; j++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\Name" + a[j].getName(), ) // and so on..
}

// alternative output with the enhanced for loop
for (NSO tmp : a) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\Name" + a.getName(), ) // and so on..
}
```

By creating an array of your NSO Object you are able to access it easily within a for loop. I hope you got an idea on how to adjust your source code. Good luck and have fun programing.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me a bit of idea.

Comment: @BennethJohn I am glad I could help. :)